# How can I automate my code using openpyxl and Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a couple of issues automating my data regarding openpyxl and pandas which is related to the length of the Dataframe DF.

The first one is regarding cells. I want to automate each row in which if it only prints the border in the number of rows equal to the length of the dataframe starting from row 3

```
       A3 = ws['A3'] 
       A3.border = Border(top=thin, left=thin, right=thin, bottom=thin)
       A3.alignment=Alignment(horizontal='general',
         vertical='bottom',
         text_rotation=0,
         wrap_text=True,
         shrink_to_fit=False,
         indent=0)
       A4 = ws['A4'] 
       A4.border = Border(top=thin, left=thin, right=thin, bottom=thin)
       A4.alignment=Alignment(horizontal='general',
         vertical='bottom',
         text_rotation=0,
         wrap_text=True,
         shrink_to_fit=False,
         indent=0)
```

The second one is regarding the dataframe. I want according to the length of the dataframe that "None" should be added to the df column a number of times

```
note =  [None, None, None,None,None,None,None,None]
df['Note'] = note
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question, you can simply do, IIUC:

```
df['Note'] = None
```